# Hibernate: fetching polymorphic property in TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance mode

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

As stated in the Hibernate documentation, `TABLE_PER_CLASS` performs awfully when fetching a polymorphic relationship

> #### [2.2.4.1. Table per class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1191)
>
> This strategy has many drawbacks (esp.
>   with polymorphic queries and
>   associations) explained in the JPA
>   spec, the Hibernate reference
>   documentation, Hibernate in Action,
>   and many other places. Hibernate work
>   around most of them implementing this
>   strategy using SQL UNION queries. It
>   is commonly used for the top level of
>   an inheritance hierarchy:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> public class Flight implements Serializable { ... }
> ```
>
> This strategy supports one-to-many
>   associations **provided that they are
>   bidirectional**. This strategy does
>   not support the IDENTITY generator
>   strategy: the id has to be shared
>   across several tables. Consequently,
>   when using this strategy, you should
>   not use AUTO nor IDENTITY.

but in this scenario I have no other choice for the inheritance strategy, so I'm looking for ways to improve the query. Comment is my concrete class that has a M:1 relationship to the abstract Commentable class.

My hope was to store a discriminator column *in Comment* that could distinguish which concrete type of Commentable it was referring to, and using a CASE inside of my query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Comments.withItemTitle",
            query = "select c.commentBody, " +
                    "case " +
                    "when n.targetType = 'video' THEN (select v.title from Video v where v.id = c.target.id) " +
                    "when n.targetType = 'message' THEN (select m.title from Message m where m.id = n.target.id) " +
                    "when n.targetType = 'blog' THEN (select b.title from Blog b where b.id = n.target.id) " +
                    "end " +
                    "from Comment c")
```

But hibernate throws an error about the nested select, saying that it can't determine its type. [This appears to be legal in postgre](http://shoaibmir.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/using-case-with-select/) - if Hibernate supported nested SELECT expressions in this way, wouldn't it fix the problem?

My next idea is to de-normalize and store the related `commentable.title` in with each comment, but I'm hesitant to do that for obvious reasons. For the purpose of this question, I can't change the inheritance structure of Commentable.

Is there any other way that I perform this query without forcing hibernate to UNION every table together?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that JPQL doesn't have a case statement.  You need to change your code to use a `@NamedNativeQuery` and rewrite your query in SQL rather than JPQL.